# What are the new video resolutions and frame rates of iPhone 6s and 6s plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

What are the new video formats supported by AVFoundation in iPhone 6s and 6s.
 below is the link to that details of iPhone 6

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2409/_index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's the supported formats for the 6s plus:

```
Format #1
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions:  192x 144, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.710, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @21.00), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1472.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #2
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions:  192x 144, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.710, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @21.00), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1472.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #3
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions:  352x 288, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:3696x3024, 
Field of View:52.900, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @10.50), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1472.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #4
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions:  352x 288, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:3696x3024, 
Field of View:52.900, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @10.50), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1472.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #5
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions:  480x 360, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.710, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @8.40), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1472.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #6
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions:  480x 360, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.710, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @8.40), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1472.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #7
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions:  640x 480, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.710, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @6.30), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1472.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #8
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions:  640x 480, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.710, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @6.30), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1472.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #9
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions:  960x 540, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:130.88 (upscales @3.88), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #10
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions:  960x 540, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:130.88 (upscales @3.88), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #11
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions:  960x 540, 
3- 60 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:130.88 (upscales @3.88), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #12
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions:  960x 540, 
3- 60 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:130.88 (upscales @3.88), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #13
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1280x 720, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:120.00 (upscales @2.91), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #14
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1280x 720, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:120.00 (upscales @2.91), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #15
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1280x 720, 
3- 60 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:120.00 (upscales @2.91), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #16
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1280x 720, 
3- 60 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:120.00 (upscales @2.91), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #17
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1280x 720, 
5-240 Frames per Second, 
Field of View:58.640, 
binned, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:65.50 (upscales @1.45), 
AF System:1, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000006-0.200000

Format #18
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1280x 720, 
5-240 Frames per Second, 
Field of View:58.640, 
binned, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:65.50 (upscales @1.45), 
AF System:1, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000006-0.200000

Format #19
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1920x1080, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:120.00 (upscales @1.94), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #20
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1920x1080, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:120.00 (upscales @1.94), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #21
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1920x1080, 
3- 60 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:120.00 (upscales @1.94), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #22
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1920x1080, 
3- 60 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4096x2304, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:120.00 (upscales @1.94), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #23
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1920x1080, 
3-120 Frames per Second, 
Field of View:58.640, 
binned, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:65.50 (upscales @1.00), 
AF System:1, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #24
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 1920x1080, 
3-120 Frames per Second, 
Field of View:58.640, 
binned, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:65.50 (upscales @1.00), 
AF System:1, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #25
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 2592x1936, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.724, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @1.56), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1840.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #26
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 2592x1936, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.724, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @1.56), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1840.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #27
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 3264x2448, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.724, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @1.24), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1840.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #28
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 3264x2448, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
High-Res Still Image Dimensions:4032x3024, 
Field of View:57.724, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @1.24), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1840.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #29
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 3840x2160, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:130.88 (upscales @1.00), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #30
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 3840x2160, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
Field of View:58.640, 
supports Video Image Stabilization, 
max zoom:130.88 (upscales @1.00), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-736.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #31
Video Range, 
Video Dimensions: 4032x3024, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
Field of View:57.724, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @1.00), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1840.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333

Format #32
Full Range, 
Video Dimensions: 4032x3024, 
3- 30 Frames per Second, 
Field of View:57.724, 
max zoom:189.00 (upscales @1.00), 
AF System:2, 
ISO:23.0-1840.0, 
Shutter Speed:0.000013-0.333333
```